# How identify type of data encoding or formatting

Tags: character-encoding

Can anyone recommend steps to identify type of data encoding or formatting?

I have following data and need to know type or formatting:

O:3:"Foo":7:{s:3:"lat";i:51;s:2:"lng";i:63;s:6:"region";s:4:"west";s:3:"bar";s:7:"Allbama";s:8:"currency";s:3:"USD";s:7:"country";s:13:"United States";s:4:"test";b:1;}

I tried searching on Google how to identify encoding type.

Comment: Where your data come from? There are *some* recognizable patterns, e.g. `s:3:"lat";` means ***s**tring of length **3** and value **`lat`***, or `i:51;` means  ***i**nteger of value **51***, or `b:1;` means ***b**oolean of value **1***, etc…